# Make tinymce text area editable by clicking anywhere on it

Tags: html, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have a tinymce panel text area in my website. By default, a person can only go into edit mode if he clicks on the first line of tinymce text area. I want that when the user clicks anywhere inside the tinymce textarea, he should go into edit mode.Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('html').click(function () {
    tinyMCE.get('#idofyoureditor').focus();
}
```

or

```
tinymce.init({
    auto_focus: "idofyoureditor"
});
```